# Problemas com JavaScript, urllib e BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, aplicação-web, python-3.x

A ideia do meu código é pegar o *link* do vídeo e rodar direto no VLC, mas cheguei a um problema: aparentemente a `urllib` não executa o código JavaScript, já que o *player* é colocado na página usando JavaScript. Vejam o meu código abaixo:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

webpage = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.animesproject.com.br/serie/885/2107/Death-Parade-Episodio-01')
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
player = soup.find(id="player_frame")
print(player)
```

A minha pergunta é: Dá pra fazer isto utilizando a `urllib`? E caso não dê, qual outro modo? Existe um *framework* para fazer isso?

**Observação**: a volta do `print` é sempre `none`.

Comment: O `urllib` apenas obtém o *markdown* (i.e. o texto) da página, ele sequer carrega os recursos externos por si só (imagens, estilos, scripts...). Para fazer o que você quer, só usando um *browser* completo mesmo, que cria o DOM, executa JavaScript, etc. Sugiro dar uma olhada no [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) ou em [outros *browsers "headless"*](https://gist.github.com/evandrix/3694955) (i.e. sem uma interface gráfica).

Answer (score 1):

Nem o urlib, nem o beautifulsoup interpretam/executam javascript.

Algumas opcoes sao:

Selenium: ele vai usar um browser de verdade como chrome ou firefox, se voce estiver usando linux podera fazer isso usando um headless display (um monitor sem cabeca, virtual)

phantomjs: que pode ser usado com selenium tambem

QT: eles tem um componente baseado em uma versao antiga do webkit, a ideia deles e voce poder ter um componente em sua janela baseado em html, ele e meio bugado e se for usar ele recomendo usar o pyhon multiprocess para executar o que voce precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Em algumas situações, como a deste problema você pode estudar um pouco o código da página e fazer as chamadas que o javascript faria.

Segue uma classe que implementei que mimetiza isso. Está em Python 2.7. Se você debugar cada função fica fácil de entender o caminho.

```
# anime.py

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re


class Anime2MP4(object):
    anime_zero_url = 'http://www.animesproject.com.br/serie/885/2162/Death-Parade-Episodio-00'  # noqa
    anime_url_format = 'http://www.animesproject.com.br/playerv52/player.php?a=0&0={0}&1={1}'  # noqa

    def build_episode_url(self, url_parameters):
        return self.anime_url_format.format(*url_parameters)

    def get_episodes_url(self):
        webpage = urllib2.urlopen(self.anime_zero_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
        id_tag = 'serie_lista_episodios'
        episodes = soup.find(id=id_tag).find_all('a', href=True)
        return [ep['href']for ep in episodes]

    def get_parameters(self):
        pars = []
        for ep in self.episodes:
            ep_split = ep.split('/')
            pars.append((ep_split[2], ep_split[3]))
        return pars

    def get_mp4_episode(self, url, quality='MQ'):
        """
        quality: Pode ser HD ou MQ
        """
        webpage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        html_content = webpage.read()
        pattern = 'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'  # noqa
        urls = set(re.findall(pattern, html_content))  # unique urls
        urls = filter(lambda s: s.endswith('.mp4'), urls)  # only .mp4
        return next((url for url in urls if quality in url), None)

    def run(self):
        self.episodes = self.get_episodes_url()
        list_episode = map(self.build_episode_url, self.get_parameters())
        mp4_links = map(self.get_mp4_episode, list_episode)
        for num, ep in enumerate(mp4_links):
            print num, ep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    anime = Anime2MP4()
    anime.run()
```